# How to handle double quotes in XML?

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I try to parse the XML output of `Stanford NLP` in java

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader("<a>"+tagged+"</a>"));
Document doc = builder.parse(is);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
NodeList nl=doc.getElementsByTagName("sentence");
```

The problem is that the XML output of `Stanford NLP` contains `"` like

```
<word wid="9" pos="``" lemma=""">"</word>
```

Then, I get the error:

```
[Fatal Error] :11:34: Element type "word" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
Exception in thread "main" org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 34; Element type "word" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:261)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
    at y.main(y.java:46)
```

I thought of replacing/escaping `"""` and `>"<`, but it is a non-standard approach and may break the entire XML.

Comment: That is not valid XML, the double-quote s in the `lemma` attribute need to be escaped correctly.  See the duplicate.

Comment: @JimGarrison I have no control over the `stanford NLP` output. How can I escape/replace `"`? This is indeed what I clarified in the question.

Comment: This may be a bug in the Stanford NLP XML output formatter.  It appears to be using CSV-style doubling for "escaping" quotes inside quotes, which is not valid in XML.  I suggest you ask on one of the [Stanford mailing lists](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/email.html), most likely `java-nlp-user@lists.stanford.edu`.  You have to join before you can post, the link to join is on the page I linked earlier.

Comment: @JimGarrison I don't think it's a bug, as it is the output format for years. The aim is not to have a standard XML format. I had to wrap the children in `<a>` to be able to parse it. I have to find a way to modify the current format. They do not alter the words.

Comment: This is indeed a bug in the XML output of the standalone POS Tagger – as far as I can see, neither the Stanford Parser or Stanford CoreNLP have this problem. I have just fixed it in commit 3a9e7df56, so the next release should produce well-formed XML.